# Realm support for Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, realm, swift3

I was wondering whether it is already possible to use Realm with the beta of Swift 3.0.

Although I see a RealmSwift-swift3.0 directory in in the Realm repo, I do not succeed to use it correctly. How should I install it from source?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use Realm with Swift 3.0, but take into account that the current version is still absolutely experimental.

You can clone the **master branch** of the [realm-cocoa](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa) repo from GitHub.

Or you can use Carthage:

```
github "realm/realm-cocoa.git" "master"
```

Or if you prefer CocoaPods:

```
pod 'RealmSwift', :git => 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', :branch => 'master'
```

If you use Carthage, remember that you must add Realm and RealmSwift frameworks manually (ignore the IBAnimatable framework):

[image: Project configuration image]

In fact, I have one of my projects with Xcode 8, Swift 3 and Realm, and it works perfectly :)

Comment: Do I indeed need the master branch? When I import this branch with Carthage and import RealmSwift I get the warning: Module file was created by an older version of the compiler. Is this branch already compiled with XCode 8?

Comment: `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer` is the command I used in order to change the default command-line tools to Xcode 8. Do it before using `carthage update` and tell me if it works.

Comment: Yes, it works! However, I feel that there are too much issues with Swift 3.0, so I think I need to wait for the release. For example Swift seems not to allow changes such as `array.appendContentsOf(realm.objects(Label))` to `array.append(contentsOf: realm.allObjects(ofType: Label))`. And a lot of other issues

Comment: In the above example, you'll need to change `Label` to `Label.self` to get the code to compile. This is a Swift 3 change and not something Realm can control, unfortunately.

Comment: Need to use two pods to ensure use of master: `pod 'RealmSwift', :git => 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', :submodules => true`
`pod 'Realm', :git => 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', :submodules => true`

Comment: Used this 2 pods and but getting errors : see here http://i.stack.imgur.com/TqJNB.png

Answer (score 5):

Starting from version 1.1.0 Realm is officially compatible with Swift 3.0/Xcode 8.0. See [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

> This release brings official support for Xcode 8, Swift 2.3 and Swift
>   3.0. Prebuilt frameworks are now built with Xcode 7.3.1 and Xcode 8.0.

Here's an extract from the install docs :

> If using Xcode 8, paste the following at the bottom of your Podfile,
>   updating the Swift version if necessary:
>
> ```
> post_install do |installer|
>   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
>     target.build_configurations.each do |config|
>       config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3' # or '3.0'
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Realm released a new version `1.1.0`. If you are using `Cocoapods` suggest you to check this [PR](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/5841) and install the version `1.1.0.rc.2` to avoid the compile error `Use Legacy Swift Language Version`.